# Как узнать id пользователя с помощью имени пользователя в телеграм?

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем привет! Я использую библиотеку aiogram python, для написания телеграм бота. Гуглил, что-то не нашёл(. Не могли бы вы подсказать как узнать id пользователя с помощью его имени пользователя? Пример, человек ввёл /get_userid, далее написал имя пользователя - @example_username, в итоге ему выдался id.

Comment: Такое уже изобрели) @username_to_id_bot

Comment: @5c0rp, очевидно, человек хочет получить ID не ручками, а через код. Цели у этого могут быть разные — добавить пользователя в какой-то список (использовать юзернеймы небезопасно, т.к. его можно сменить, а любой другой может его переиспользовать после освобождения).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Спустя 11 дней, и куча перерытой инфы в гугле. Я нашел ответ. Я использовал библиотеку telethon. Логинитесь https://my.telegram.org/auth, и создаете app. Далее получаете api_id и api_hash.
Я оставлю здесь асинхронную функцию для получения юзера:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest
async def get_user(username):
    async with TelegramClient('ваш username', API_ID, API_HASH) as client:
        user = await client(GetFullUserRequest(username))
    return user
```

Надеюсь кому нибудь помог)

Comment: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'get_user' was never awaited get_user('@nickname')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Увы, не работает ваш способ, что я делаю не так?
:(

Comment: @НикитаЁжиков функцию нужно через `await get_user(username)`