# telethon api python - как мне отправлять сообщения пользователям?

Tags: python, telethon

у меня есть список с пользователями и как мне будет правильно сделать отправку сообщения?

я пробовал по `username`, но не у всех он есть.

возможно сделать отправку по `id` пользователя,
или есть ещё способ сделать отправку сообщения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `client.send_message(user_id, text)`

Comment: а вот вопрос , у всех же пользователей есть user_id и у всех он виден да ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

client.send_message("ivan", "my message") - отправка по имени профиля (не путать с @ivan)

upd: можно отправить как client.send_message("@ivan_jhony", "message")

Comment: а если таких пользователь с именем ivan осень много ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1162120/Как-узнать-id-пользователя-с-помощью-имени-пользователя-в-телеграм - то что по быстрому нашёл в интернете. Надеюсь поможет

Comment: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/users.html?highlight=GetFullUserRequest#retrieving-full-information - и вот ссылка на документацию и на метод, который должен помочь решить проблему